# Evaluate Your Site -- A Check for Quality

Tags: discussion

One of the most important aspects of being a Stack Exchange site is quality. Yes, there are lots of metrics that one can use to "measure" a site, but we don't really care about those as much as we care about a site providing expert answers to good questions. To that end, we're encouraging self-evaluations on our sites!

Meta sites often see people discussing specific questions that have been closed to determine whether or not they can (or should) be reopened, but it's rare that anyone looks at questions that are open and answered. Are they better than what the Internet has to offer? Are we making the Internet better?

Here's a rough guide:

- Below, you'll find ten questions randomly selected from your site.
- For each question, search the internet for the question as if you were the asker!
- If our answer is good (complete, well-written, answers the question, found in search results, etc) then **vote it up**!
- If our answer is bad (incomplete, poorly-written, off-topic, unfindable, etc) then **vote it down**!

Comment with anything you feel is worth noting, or to explain your voting choice. We have a rough guide to better/par/worse [right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQxi7.png). **If your result is par, make a choice to vote up or down.**

Remember that our goal is to make the internet a better place. If you find yourself unable to decide how to vote, ask yourself: does this question and/or answer make the internet better? How you answer that question should determine your vote.

Talk to your fellow community members about how your site is doing and what you all can improve. Above all else, remember: this is a *team effort!*

**Please note: this evaluation will close on 4 April 2012! Get your answers in by then!**

Comment: Thank you for your participation, everyone! :D

Answer (score 4):

[using single or double bracket - bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash)

Vote and (optionally) please leave a comment according to the guide above.

Comment: Good question & great answers, but 2 questions on SO & one from ServerFault (all good too) seem to push it down a bit in the search results. (+1 anyway)

Answer (score 4):

[Where to find the source file of function pause(void) and sigsuspend(set)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32536/where-to-find-the-source-file-of-function-pausevoid-and-sigsuspendset)

Vote and (optionally) please leave a comment according to the guide above.

Comment: We're easily at the top of search results since it's so specific; really good answer

Answer (score 4):

[What's the meaning of the slash in crontab?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32027/whats-the-meaning-of-the-slash-in-crontab)

Vote and (optionally) please leave a comment according to the guide above.

Comment: This is explained everywhere (it's right on the man page), but we're pretty high in the search results, and the answer is accurate

Answer (score 3):

[How do I use curl to download content from sourceforge?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31821/how-do-i-use-curl-to-download-content-from-sourceforge)

Vote and (optionally) please leave a comment according to the guide above.

Comment: We lost out to a blog and sourceforge's own bug tracker, which both have the same fairly simple answer as us. There's not much to this other than knowing how sourceforge works and what switch to pass to `curl`

Answer (score 3):

[Does CentOS fall into System V family? How is it considered to be while comparing with Unix System V family?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31997/does-centos-fall-into-system-v-family-how-is-it-considered-to-be-while-comparin)

Vote and (optionally) please leave a comment according to the guide above.

Comment: ...this question is awfully-phrased but it is extremely good historical question, requiring more work. Unfortunately now hidden, perhaps a good place for necromancer to work ...

Comment: hhh's edit helped a lot. We're surprisingly high in search results; I don't know much about the subject, but the answer seems good

Answer (score 3):

[Can I set how long ssh-agent keeps keys in memory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32609/can-i-set-how-long-ssh-agent-keeps-keys-in-memory)

Vote and (optionally) please leave a comment according to the guide above.

Comment: I wouldn't have phrased the title this way, but did a search for the title I would've used and found us as the first result, so yay. Another answer that just quotes the man page, but I'm not sure what else you'd say

Answer (score 2):

[How to bypass GNOME Terminal when sending keyboard input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32552/how-to-bypass-gnome-terminal-when-sending-keyboard-input)

Vote and (optionally) please leave a comment according to the guide above.

Comment: We were the first useful result for "send hotkey through gnome terminal". The answer doesn't really solve the problem, but I'm not sure Gnome Terminal has the functionality the OP wants. I would call this par, but I guess we're supposed to vote one way or the other

Answer (score 0):

[Where does Firefox 10 look for plugins?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31837/where-does-firefox-10-look-for-plugins)

Vote and (optionally) please leave a comment according to the guide above.

Comment: ...too localized, becomes rotten -- belongs to chat.

Comment: This is covered on about 40000 websites, but we do somehow make it into the early search results for some queries (not "firefox plugin path" or "where does firefox store plugins" though, which are what I would've tried). It's certainly not too localized, it's exactly the opposite, but I have no idea if the answer is right, and the OP abandoned the question. If I'm forced to pick one, I guess -1

Answer (score 0):

[Which arch linux should I download?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31963/which-arch-linux-should-i-download)

Vote and (optionally) please leave a comment according to the guide above.

Comment: ...too localized.

Comment: We're destroyed in search results by official Arch documentation, which isn't a big surprise. The question doesn't really have anything to do with Arch, it's just confusion over architecture nomenclature. The answers are fine, but the lack of search position apparently makes this "bad" anyway (how can something make the internet worse if nobody can even find it?)

Answer (score -1):

[Ubuntu Server - Access webserver from other LAN computer, setting up SSH or FTP, closing ports?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32353/ubuntu-server-access-webserver-from-other-lan-computer-setting-up-ssh-or-ftp)

Vote and (optionally) please leave a comment according to the guide above.

Comment: Not a good question to start with - too many things asked. Answer isn't bad, but can't be real good or stellar with such a broad question, _and_ it is kind of strangely findable nonetheless...  (so -1 from me)

Comment: He crammed like nine questions into one; I'm tempted to close it, but I guess I should leave it until this is over. I also couldn't find any of the individual questions in search results, so -1